# VBA- if criteria met, place desired text in the next column

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vba

I would like to turn an `IF` formula into VBA code:

I have "Alphanumeric string 255 max char" with note based descriptions in Column"Q" 
I have a blank Column"R"

Formula in "R2"

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sc",Q2)),"Service Call","")
```

I have about 39,000 rows to do this with, which is why I would like to try in VBA.

What shall be the code, if I needed a different instance?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sp",Q2)),"Springs","") **Multiple conditions for ...

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Amarr",Q2)),"Door","") **Multiple conditions for ...
```

Comment: Use a variant array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do what you want.

```
Sub ColQtoColR()
Dim FirstRow, LastRow, RowCount As Long
Dim GCell As Range

FirstRow = 2
LastRow = 39000
For RowCount = FirstRow To LastRow
Set GCell = Cells(RowCount, 17)
    If InStr(GCell, "sc") = 1 Then
        GCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Service Call"
    ElseIf InStr(GCell, "sp") = 1 Then
        GCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Springs"
    ElseIf InStr(GCell, "Amarr") = 1 Then
        GCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Door"
    Else
        GCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    End If
Next RowCount

End Sub
```

More conditions can easily be added, and the number of rows processed can be changed. It only took a few seconds on my old laptop to run. If two of these strings are present in the text in the Q column, then it will match the last one tested.

Comment: This works just how I want but awfully slow, I'll take it. Thank you kindly. Make sure string in Col"Q" doesnt have an #error or it will stop.